# Extraction reactions data from facebook via restFb java api?

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-graph-api, restfb

The new facebook api allows us to get reactions on a post on a page, for this fb has created a **reactions edge** 
I am able to extract data from this edge by simple hitting post-id/reactions from the graph api explorer.

Here is the graph api request :-

> 1497117777255241_1526440124323006/reactions

and the response data

> {   "data": [
>       {
>         "id": "100008182891350",
>         "name": "Harsh Sharma",
>         "type": "LOVE"
>       }   ],   "paging": {
>       "cursors": {
>         "before": "TVRBd01EQTRNVGd5T0RreE16VXdPakUwTmpRd01EQTROalk2TnpnNE5qUTRNRE0zT1RFek16RXkZD",
>         "after": "TVRBd01EQTRNVGd5T0RreE16VXdPakUwTmpRd01EQTROalk2TnpnNE5qUTRNRE0zT1RFek16RXkZD"
>       }   } }

now i try to do the same using the java rest fb api in which I first extract the post and then using that object I call the get reactions method on it but I dont get any data.
Here is the sample code for the same :-

```
reactionsCount=post.getReactionsCount();
        System.out.println("post id-->"+post.getId()+"  reactions--->"+post.getReactionsCount());
        reactionsObj=post.getReactions();
```

for the above post id : there is a reaction on it but I am getting the reaction count as zero via restFB, but I am getting data from graph api.

The reactionObj is also null every time (obtained via       reactionsObj=post.getReactions();
)

```
if(reactionsObj!=null)
            {
                System.out.println("bring it on reactions-------");
                    for (ReactionItem reactionListItem : reactionsObj.getData()) 
                    {
                        reactionsMap.put("id", reactionListItem.getId());
                        reactionsMap.put("name", reactionListItem.getName() );
                        reactionsMap.put("type",reactionListItem.getType() );


                    }
}
```

I am getting posts/comments/likes successfully, only the reactions edge is creating problems. 
Please let me know where I am going wrong.

***Edit***

```
Connection<Post>  postSearch =FacebookClientBean.getFacebookclient().fetchConnection(pageId+"/feed", Post.class);
```

Comment: please provide the fetchObject call you made to retrieve the Post. This would help a lot to investigate this.

Comment: I have edited the question to include the call

Comment: and there's the problem. You need to add the fields parameter to access the reactions. Try something like: `fetchConnection(pageId+"/feed", Post.class, Parameter.with("fields","reactions.summary(1)"));`

Comment: Thanks @Norbert ,I guess this is what was missing, but now I am getting the following exception  Received Facebook error response of
 type OAuthException: (#12) Reactions read API requires version v2.6 or higher (
code 12, subcode null).  I am using the access token from api v2.6 only, trying to figure out the solution

Comment: You should create a FacebookClient instance with the given Version. Like `new DefaultFacebookClient(accessToken, Version.VERSION_2_6);` and restfb needs to be at least version 1.22.0

Comment: Perfect @Norbert , Thanks a lot.Was using a deprecated function which I forgot to change after updating the jar. You should put all this in the answer so that I could accept it. Thanks again

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Collected solutions from the comments:**

to get reactions on a Post you have to add the field in the request like this:

```
fetchConnection(pageId+"/feed", Post.class, Parameter.with("fields","reactions.summary(1)"));
```

An error message with the content *requires version v2.6 or higher* is a hint the wrong Graph API version is used to request the node.
Select the correct `Version` in the `DefaultFacebookClient` constructor:

```
new DefaultFacebookClient(accessToken, Version.VERSION_2_6);
```